# My 2nd range copys perfect but the first does nothing?

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl, pywin32

So I've got to different blocks that are nearly identical, the second range copys perfectly but the first does nothing. Any idea whats going on? I've tried everything I can think of. I checked the macros to make sure they weren't clearing the range after it was pasted into the workbook, the macros are stopped before doing anything due to the range being empty.

```
import win32com.client
import openpyxl

#1st range
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Export.xlsx") 
sheet = wb["Export"] 


template = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Wall Types Live.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True) #Add file name
temp_sheet = template["Raw Export"] 



def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []

    for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1,1):

        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)

        rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

    return rangeSelected




def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetReceiving,copiedData):
    countRow = 0
    for i in range(startRow,endRow+1,1):
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            sheetReceiving.cell(row = i, column = j).value = copiedData[countRow][countCol]
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1
def createData():
    print("Processing first...")
    selectedRange = copyRange(1,2,11,100000,sheet) 
    pastingRange = pasteRange(1,12,11,100000,temp_sheet,selectedRange) 

    print("Complete!")

Go = createData()
#Run macros
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'C:\Users\tyler\Desktop\Beef Web\Wall Types Live.xlsm', ReadOnly=0)
xl.Application.Run('Python')
del xl
#2nd range
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Wall Types Live.xlsm") 
sheet = wb["E1 Final"] 


template = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Export.xlsx") 
temp_sheet = template["Export"] 



def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []

    for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1,1):

        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)

        rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

    return rangeSelected



def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetReceiving,copiedData):
    countRow = 0
    for i in range(startRow,endRow+1,1):
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            sheetReceiving.cell(row = i, column = j).value = copiedData[countRow][countCol]
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1
def createData():
    print("Processing second...")
    selectedRange = copyRange(1,1,19,100000,sheet) 
    pastingRange = pasteRange(1,1,19,100000,temp_sheet,selectedRange) 

    template.save("Finishtest.xlsx")
    print("Complete!")

Go = createData()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@APhillips I finally got it running. openpyxl has an issue not relating to my code so I ended up just doing the whole process with win32com. here is the working code.

```
import win32com.client
import openpyxl

def CopyIn_run_macros():
    #Run macros
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    BC=xl.Workbooks.Open('Processing File 1 Path')
    xl.Application.Run('Python2')
    EXP=xl.Workbooks.Open('Import Data File Path')
    print("Importing Export To Processing Sheet....")
    EXP.Sheets('Sheet1').Range('A2:K100000').Copy()
    BC.Sheets('Sheet1').Paste(BC.Sheets('Sheet1').Range('A12'))
    EXP.Close(True)
    print("Complete.")
    print("Running Macros....")
    xl.Application.Run('Python')
    print("Complete.")
    print("Exporting Export Processed Data....")
    FIN=xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Finish.xlsx')
    BC.Sheets('Sheet2').Range('A1:T100000').Copy()
    FIN.Sheets('Sheet1').Paste(FIN.Sheets('Sheet1').Range('A1'))
    BC.Sheets('Sheet3').Range('A1:H100000').Copy()
    FIN.Sheets('Sheet2').Paste(FIN.Sheets('Sheet2').Range('A1'))
    BC.Sheets('Sheet4').Range('A1:AG100000').Copy()
    FIN.Sheets('Sheet3').Paste(FIN.Sheets('Sheet3').Range('A1'))
    FIN.Close(True)
    print("Complete.")
    del xl


CopyIn_run_macros()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating functions (`copyRange` and `pasteRange` and `createData`) and then recreating them for the "second run". This is not good coding practice and will cause unexpected effects. I have adjusted your code to have only one definition of each function. At the end, when you call your `main` function, it will execute the code in the order you specified, and using `createData` you can call the values for each range selection.

```py
import win32com.client
import openpyxl

#1st range
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Export.xlsx") 
sheet = wb["Export"] 


template = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Wall Types Live.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True) #Add file name
temp_sheet = template["Raw Export"] 


def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []
    sheet.unmerge_cells(start_row=startRow, start_column=startCol, end_row=endRow, end_column=endCol)
    for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1):

        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)

        rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

    return rangeSelected


def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheetReceiving,copiedData):
    countRow = 0
    for i in range(startRow,endRow+1):
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1):
            sheetReceiving.cell(row = i, column = j).value = copiedData[countRow][countCol]
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1

def run_macros():
    #Run macros
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'C:\Users\tyler\Desktop\Beef Web\Wall Types Live.xlsm', ReadOnly=0)
    xl.Application.Run('Python')
    del xl
    #2nd range
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Wall Types Live.xlsm") 
    sheet = wb["E1 Final"] 


    template = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Export.xlsx") 
    temp_sheet = template["Export"] 



def createData():
    print("Processing first...")
    selectedRange = copyRange(1,2,11,100000,sheet) 
    pastingRange = pasteRange(1,12,11,100000,temp_sheet,selectedRange) 

    print("Complete!")

    run_macros()

    print("Processing second...")
    selectedRange = copyRange(1,1,19,100000,sheet) 
    pastingRange = pasteRange(1,1,19,100000,temp_sheet,selectedRange) 

    template.save("Finishtest.xlsx")
    print("Complete!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createData()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this is literally the first thing I've ever done with Python so I'm still a bit lost. I tried your code and its still leaving the sheet with a blank range. as well as its now throwing an error. `AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only`

Comment: It's impossible for me to debug since I don't have your Excel or Template files, but you can try using `unmerge_cells`. I updated the code above.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I'll fiddle with it until I get it to run then post an update.